# Laravel 5 Angular2 change the default base href

Tags: laravel, angular

I have an existing working app in Laravel, the client wants to add another features, but this time he wanted to use Angular2 instead of the previous jQuery.

I created new folder inside resources folder using angular-cli tools. The example angular app that created tru angular-cli works fine when running ng serve, that would point to //localhost:3000/ . But I need the default angular base to something like this

```
myproject.dev/angular
```

myproject.dev contains the homepage for the Laravel project, so my user module with angular should be in

```
     myproject.dev/angular   //dev
     www.myproject.com/angular  //production
```

Running

```
  ng build --bh /angular/
```

Would be successful in

```
 localhost:4200/angular
```

But would display 404 in

```
 myproject.dev/angular
```

I created a route

```
 Route::get('/angular/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
 });
```

The welcome.blade.php is the

```
 resources/views/welcome.blade.php
```

I just copy paste the default index.html inside the angular app to the welcome.blade.php

```
  <!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Angular 2</title>
        <base href="/angular/">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
     </head>
    <body>
       <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Is a subdomain envisageable? It would be way easier.

Comment: If there is no other option, maybe I would use a subdomain, but I don't want to separate the codebase, just inside the laravel project but in separate folder.

Comment: Normally, it would not be a problem to make it run like that, just be sure to have access to all the assets and rightly define the path to node_modules in your systemjs (which is, by the way, not present on your code sample?). The only matter I can think of is for the Rewriting, every request in this folder have to be redirected to index.html

Comment: When running ng build, it will copy to the dist folder, so I think returning the index.html inside dist folder would solve the problem, but I dont konw how to return that file from route like return view(resources/angular/dist/index.html)